# How to use non-English characters in Godot?

Tags: arabic, non-english, godot, farsi

I want to use non-English characters in Godot, but when I write them (In every node, like a Label or a Button) and run the project, the text does not display. For example, I write some Arabic characters in a Label and run the project, but I do not see anything. But I can see the characters in editor separately and reversely. ("عالم" is displayed "م ل ا ع")

I know that this problem is discussed on GitHub, but there was not any good solution. Please advise me a good and simple solution to solve this problem. I think it is not solved so far.

Comment: I found a great and completed solution for Persian language. I think we can generalize it for other same languages.
*Mohammad Reza Baghbani* has written a good module to solve this problem [here](http://mrbaghbani.blog.ir/1394/12/25/%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D9%86%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%DA%AF%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AC%DB%8C%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%86-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D9%BE%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%A7). You can download it from [here](http://bayanbox.ir/download/3800959900793331477/PersianWordsSet.gd) directly.
Thanks to *Mohammad Reza Baghbani*

Comment: JJJ may not have been clear in their comment to your answer. It is good for you to self-answer the way you did (and you should accept your own answer). It helps other people find this. The point was just that it is better to bring the important points of the linked information here so that if the link goes away, the information won't be lost. Don't just copy the information verbatim; that's unfair to the original writer. But bringing the important ideas here would be very valuable, especially since the linked article is not in English. Thanks for the contribution!

Answer (score 1):

The default `Label` font in Godot doesn't support non-ASCII characters.

You can try to change the font in your `Label` node to one that supports non-ASCII symbols by picking a font from your computer, or if it doesn't exist on your device, uploading it from some site like [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com), and choosing an arabic-supporting font, like [Amiri](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Amiri?subset=arabic).

After choosing the font for your Label node, open the Custom Fonts property in the editor of the node, and create a `DynamicFont`, and in `Font` => `Font Data` press `Load` and choose your font in the opened window in the file system (`.ttf` or any another font extension).